# Использование библиотеки jquery-lang-js в js файле

Tags: javascript, library

Пользуюсь библиотекой jquery-lang-js (https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js) для смены языка на сайте. Столкнулся с проблемой, как поменять язык в js файле? Ибо половина контента на сайте у меня подгружается через js

Пример:

```
function show(value) {
  var content = `
            <li class="custom">
            Текст который надо перевести на английский.`+value+`
             </li>
          `;
          $('ul.content-list').prepend(content);
}
```

Comment: С атрибутом `lang` не получается? По возможности добавьте самодостаточный пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изучил документацию, там есть функция которая работает внутри js.

```
alert(window.lang.translate('Some text to translate'));
```